# Generating executable with ld

Tags: gcc, ld

I have problems generating a small hello-world program in C with ld as linker.

These are my steps so far:

```
gcc -c hello.c
ld -o hello hello.o -lc

./hello
-bash: ./hello: no such file or directory
```

`hello.c`'s source is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    puts("Hello, world!");
    return 0;
}
```

It seems I have missed an important part here. Neither `gcc` nor `ld` had any errors and both ended with return value 0.

Please do not tell me "just use `gcc -o hello hello.c`"! I have browsed like 10 boards and people always gave that answer. I want to know how to do it the ld-way.

Comment: The invocation of `ld` is a bit tricky, and depends on the platform, the version of the toolchain, etc. so generally that's why it is suggested to be used only via the `gcc` wrapper. By the way, have you had a look at `file hello`? What does it output?

Comment: It's merely my wish to know how to do it without pretty tools like gcc. In many Makefiles the compilation and linking step are seperated and this is also what I want to get.

Comment: `file hello` outputs: `hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped`

Comment: in Makefiles, it's idiomatic to use `gcc`, instead of `ld` immediately, for linking (and `gcc -c` for compiling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to understand what GCC is actually doing, run it with the `-v` flag. (For example, `gcc -v -o hello hello.c`.)

You're missing some pieces of code that GCC would normally instruct the linker to include. If you look at the output of `gcc -v`, you'll see things like `crt1.o -lgcc -lgcc_s` and others.

See also the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Link-Options.html) for options such as `-nostartfiles`, `-nodefaultlibs`, and `-nostdlib` for some context on these extra bits of code that are being linked in behind the scenes.